# Custom file types upload using Dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, php, apk, dropzone.js

I need to upload files to the database using Dropzonejs. It accepts image file types. But doesn't support other file types. I went through the accepted files document as well. 
But I couldn't find a way to upload **.apk** files. Please help me to solve this problem. Or else please suggest similar library to perform the task.

Comment: You can specify supported file types, so you can add .apk to the list

Answer (score 0):

Please see: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles

I believe when you instantiate your DZ (or in main config) you specify extensions and mime types in a comma separated list. I don't know the mime type for .apk files but likely 'text/plain' so maybe you could try adding the option as in this example:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dz", {
    ...
    acceptedFiles: ".apk,text/plain",
    ...
})
```